# Json encoded array issues

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to figure out what my issue is between the jQuery ajax call and the php return json encode.

When I look at the response in the console it shows...

```
{"output_status":"Success","output_title":"Login Success","output_message":"Successful login! Sending you to the dashboard"}
```

When I do a console.log(data) it shows...

```
Object { output_status="Success", output_title="Login Success", output_message="Successful login! Sending you to the dashboard"}
```

With my following code does anyone see anything that could be a potentional problem.

```
php controller function
function submit()
{ 
    $output_array = array('output_status' => $output_status, 'output_title' => $output_title, 'output_message' => $output_message);

    echo json_encode($output_array);
}

js
success:  function(data) {
console.log(data);
if (data.ouput_status == 'Success') {
        window.location.href = 'dashboard';
}
}
```

Comment: What *is* your issue?

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is here

Comment: If the issue was not `ouput`, I'd also try a `dataType: 'json'` within the jquery array.

Comment: Good point but it was the simple mistake below in the first answe.r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't mention your problem but I think it's a typo you miss `t` in output spell here,

```
data.ouput_status
      ^
```

Comment: That's right I can't believe this was such a simple mistake.

Comment: Happens..It's just need fresh eyes pair :)